# The "Csc" task failed unexpectedly Could not load type System.ValueTuple 3 from assembly mscorlib Version=4.0.0.0,

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, dependencies, .net-assembly

While building the project in MS Visual studio 2017, it comes up with above error, i tried with restore NuGet packages, and the visuals studio shows this error, please help to resolve it

```
"The "Csc" task failed unexpectedly.
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.ValueTuple`3' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.ManagedToolTask.GenerateCommandLineCommands()
   at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() AppModelv2-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet          
"
```

Comment: What is your .Net framework version?Also what kind of project you are building?ASP.NET ?Console?GUI?

Comment: The .Net framework is 4.5.2

Comment: The project Type is ASP.NET Web application. i download it from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp#option-2-register-and-manually-configure-your-application-and-code-sample

Comment: I use the option "Register and download your quickstart app " to use the Microsoft authentication in my application from  https://portal.azure.com

Comment: I have already answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For .NET 4.6.2 or lower

you need to install the NuGet package System.ValueTuple.

```
Install-Package "System.ValueTuple"
```

If this does not work please make the follow steps.

1.Locate you project’s packages folder

2.Delete the folder

3.Rebuild your project

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it didn't work, i tried installing system.valuetuple package, also tried by updating the .Net framework to 4.6.1, still facing the same issue.

Comment: Thanks again unfortunately Deleting the packages folder is also didn't work.

Comment: Could you please check your csproj file and see whether system value type is hardcoded or not and if yes just remove it.

Comment: Thank You very much So_oP, that was my first question on stackoverflow i got answered so fast, 

I applied above three solutions, then restart the MS Visual studio and it works like charm.
also Thanks Stackoverflow you are doing a great job. i appreciate your services..